# Google Cloud IoT core exercise

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

I am working on Google Cloud IoT core and there I came across a problem in one of the samples (end-to-end example) provided in the online docs: [google cloud iot exercise](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/end-to-end-sample)

There are two scripts, for Server and Device, and while running the device script I am facing this problem:

[image]

Comment: the code of those scripts are:-


https://github.com/aadharbhatt/pub-sub-work/blob/master/cloudiot_pubsub_example_mqtt_device.py
 

https://github.com/aadharbhatt/pub-sub-work/blob/master/cloudiot_pubsub_example_server.py

Comment: __Please add some details to your post itself and to the title.__
This is not a chat box but a problem solving library. Questions should be carefully edited so not only those that can provide a sollution, but also those that have a similar problem in a different context can find your question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

From the commandline args, it looks like you're passing in rsa_cert.pem, which is your SSL private key. As @class said, you need to wget the Google root certificate (wget https://pki.google.com/roots.pem) and then pass the path to downloaded roots.pem for the --ca_certs argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your firewall (e.g. the Cloud Shell Machine) is blocking Python from connecting via port 8883. Can you try calling the `cloudiot_pubsub_example_mqtt_device.py` script with the port set to 443, e.g.

```
python <your_existing_parameters> --mqtt_bridge_port=443
```

You may also want to try using [the HTTP device sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api-client/http_example) to publish messages as it also doesn't use port 8883, which may be blocked on your network.

In my tests, I was only able to run the exercise from the Google Cloud Shell after setting my port to 443, this hopefully will resolve the issue for you.

**Note** If you're encountering issues with verifying the server certificate, you need to download the Google root certificate by calling:

```
wget https://pki.google.com/roots.pem
```

**Update** You may also want to try to set the Python version in your virtual environment to Python 2 by setting up the virtual environment as:

```
virtualenv env --python=python2
```

Comment: At Port 443 ssl certificate verification failed

Answer (score 0):

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSv3s.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cloudiot_pubsub_example_mqtt_device.py", line 249, in <module>
    main()
  File "cloudiot_pubsub_example_mqtt_device.py", line 213, in main
    client.connect(args.mqtt_bridge_hostname, args.mqtt_bridge_port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 
768, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 
927, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 788, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed 
(_ssl.c:581)
```